# Buenos dias tengo este error y no se como solucionar se origina por un trigger para modificar el stoc

Tags: php, html, mysql

este es el error

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'IDproducto' in 'where clause' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto\ecommerce-html-template\Cliente\Catalogo\pagar.php:49 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto\ecommerce-html-template\Cliente\Catalogo\pagar.php(49): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto\ecommerce-html-template\Cliente\Catalogo\pagar.php on line 49

este es el trigger

```
BEGIN
DECLARE StockActual INT;
SET @STOCKACTUAL:=(SELECT stock FROM productos WHERE IDproducto=new.IDproducto);
UPDATE productos SET
stock=@STOCKACTUAL-new.cantidad
WHERE IDproducto=new.IDproducto;

END
```

y este es la parte de insert de detalle pedido

```
`introducir el código aquí`foreach($_SESSION['CARRITO'] as $indice=>$producto){
    $sentecia=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `detallePedido` 
        (`ID`, `IDventa`, `IDproducto`, `precioUnitario`, `cantidad`) 
        VALUES (NULL, :IDventa, :IDproducto, :precioUnitario, :cantidad);");

        $sentecia->bindParam(":IDventa",$idVenta);
        $sentecia->bindParam(":IDproducto",$producto['codigo']);
        $sentecia->bindParam(":precioUnitario",$producto['precio']);
        $sentecia->bindParam(":cantidad",$producto['cantidad']);
        $sentecia->execute();
}
```

ayuda por favor

Comment: El mensaje de error es claro, te está diciendo que no hay una columna llamada `IDproducto` en la tabla `productos` ¿? o en la tabla que estés referenciando en **la línea 49 del archivo `pagar.php`**. Ahí ocurre el error, deberías compartir esa parte del código PHP. El INSERT que muestras no tiene nada que ver aquí.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto\ecommerce-html-template\Cliente\Catalogo\pagar.php:49 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto\ecommerce-html-template\Cliente\Catalogo\pagar.php(49): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto\ecommerce-html-template\Cliente\Catalogo\pagar.php on line 49

ahora me arroja este

Comment: Lee el mensaje de error: **`Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'IDproducto' in 'where clause' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto\ecommerce-html-template\Cliente\Catalogo\pagar.php:49`** Te está diciendo que la columna que usas en la cláusula `where` no existe. Y te dice que el error ocurre en la línea `49` del archivo `pagar.php`. Si no sabes depurar en base a ese mensaje, entonces agrega a la pregunta lo que tienes en esa línea, pues no es lo que nos estás mostrando.

Comment: Estamos en lo mismo. Por favor, muestra lo que hay en la dichosa línea 49 de tu archivo `pagar.php`

Comment: 40foreach($_SESSION['CARRITO'] as $indice=>$producto){
    41$sentecia=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `detallePedido` 
        42(`ID`, `IDventa`, `IDproducto`, `precioUnitario`, `cantidad`) 
        43VALUES (NULL, :IDventa, :IDproducto, :precioUnitario, :cantidad);");
44
    45    $sentecia->bindParam(":IDventa",$idVenta);
    46    $sentecia->bindParam(":IDproducto",$producto['codigo']);
    47    $sentecia->bindParam(":precioUnitario",$producto['precio']);
    48    $sentecia->bindParam(":cantidad",$producto['cantidad']);
    49    $sentecia->execute();

Comment: En el TRIGGER, prueba a cambiar esto así: `SET @STOCKACTUAL:=(SELECT stock FROM productos WHERE IDproducto=new.IDproducto LIMIT 1);`

Comment: 'BEGIN
DECLARE StockActual INT;
SET @STOCKACTUAL:=(SELECT stock FROM productos WHERE IDproducto=new.IDproducto LIMIT 1);
UPDATE productos SET
stock=@STOCKACTUAL-new.cantidad
WHERE IDproducto=new.IDproducto;

END'

tambien debo cambiarlo abajo?

Comment: No necesariamente. El error de cardinalidad ahí es porque estás intentando setear una variable desde una consulta que devuelve más de una fila. De todos modos, tienes algún problema en tus tablas, porque en la tabla `stock` no debería haber filas de productos repetidas, una vez el código fucione deberías normalizar eso, agregando una restricción UNIQUE a la tabla para evitar que haya más de una información de stock por producto, de lo contrario tendrás un lío en tus datos.

Comment: me arroja este error 

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'IDproducto' in 'where clause' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto\ecommerce-html-template\Cliente\Catalogo\pagar.php:49 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto\ecommerce-html-template\Cliente\Catalogo\pagar.php(49): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto\ecommerce-html-template\Cliente\Catalogo\pagar.php on line 49

Comment: pero si cambio idproducto (tabla detallepedido) por codigo(tabla productos)
de esta forma
BEGIN
DECLARE StockActual INT;
SET @STOCKACTUAL:=(SELECT stock FROM productos WHERE codigo=codigo LIMIT 1);
UPDATE productos SET
stock=@STOCKACTUAL-new.cantidad
WHERE IDproducto=new.IDproducto;

END

Comment: me da este 

me da este error
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'IDproducto' in 'where clause' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto\ecommerce-html-template\Cliente\Catalogo\pagar.php:49 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto\ecommerce-html-template\Cliente\Catalogo\pagar.php(49): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto\ecommerce-html-template\Cliente\Catalogo\pagar.php on line 49

Comment: y si cambio tambien el de abajo asi

BEGIN
DECLARE StockActual INT;
SET @STOCKACTUAL:=(SELECT stock FROM productos WHERE codigo=codigo LIMIT 1);
UPDATE productos SET
stock=@STOCKACTUAL-new.cantidad
WHERE codigo=new.IDproducto;

END

Comment: me da este 
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'IDventa' cannot be null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto\ecommerce-html-template\Cliente\Catalogo\pagar.php:49 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto\ecommerce-html-template\Cliente\Catalogo\pagar.php(49): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto\ecommerce-html-template\Cliente\Catalogo\pagar.php on line 49

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta indicando los cambios que has hecho y agregando los nuevos errores... es complicado resolver esto desde comentarios. Ejecuta también en la base de datos `SHOW CREATE TABLE elNombreDeLaTabla` de aquellas tablas que te dice que tienen problemas y agrégalo a la pregunta. Tienes muchos errores de diseño en las tablas y si no vemos cómo están compuestas nos podemos pasar horas aquí tratando de adivinar tu contexto. Conviene que leas detenidamente los mensajes de error, porque son bastante claros, sólo que están en inglés, pero hay que aprender inglés si vas a programar.

Comment: Si te dice que la columna IDVenta no puede ser nula, depura la variable que intentas insertar en dicha columna mediante un `var_dump($idVenta);` y revisa si es nula y por qué lo es.